# Increasing animation speed (CSS) of transform animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to find a way to speed up the transform (flip about the y axis) in 0.05 seconds. Basically, the image flips in 0.05 seconds. The flip animation however does not change despite what I did in CSS. Please help

CSS

```
<style> 

.a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;

  position: relative;
  animation-name: box;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  transition: transform 0.05s; 
 
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;


}

@keyframes box {
  0%   { left: var(--rando0); top: var(--rando1); transform: rotateY(180deg);}
  25%  {   transform: rotateY(180deg) left: var(--rando2); top: var(--rando3);}
  50%  { left: var(--rando4); top: var(--rando5);  transform: rotateY(180deg);}
  75%  {   transform: rotateY(180deg) left: var(--rando6); top: var(--rando7);}
  100% { left: var(--rando8); top: var(--rando9);  transform: rotateY(180deg);}


}
```

HTML

```
<img src="image.gif" alt="prgm" class='a left'  class='character'>
```

JS

```
<script>
const root = document.querySelector(":root"); // we first get the root element
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  root.style.setProperty(`--rando${i}`, `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1}px`);
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: First why img does have two classes attributes, Second changing animation-duration to less number speeding up the animation.

Comment: As I understand it you want the whole animation - that is the random moving of the item, to take 10 seconds, but you want the item to flip about its Y axis just once on 0.5 seconds and then stay flipped. Is that correct?

Comment: ..or, is the E to keep rotating constantly?

Answer (score 0):

You can have two animations running at the same time. This snippet keeps the left/top animation at 10s and introduces a rotate animation at 0.5s. (At 0.05s the rotation gives very flashing result which didn't seem to be likely what you wanted).

```js
const root = document.querySelector(":root"); // we first get the root element
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  root.style.setProperty(`--rando${i}`, `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1}px`);
}
```

```css
.a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: box, rotate;
  animation-duration: 10s, 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0%,
  49.99%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  50%,
  99.99% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes box {
  0% {
    left: var(--rando0);
    top: var(--rando1);
  }
  25% {
    left: var(--rando2);
    top: var(--rando3);
  }
  50% {
    left: var(--rando4);
    top: var(--rando5);
  }
  75% {
    left: var(--rando6);
    top: var(--rando7);
  }
  100% {
    left: var(--rando8);
    top: var(--rando9);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRzhbV48pXypX9otxEVYrZ1etEOZqym7693twATGzSGqg&s" alt="prgm" class='a left' class='character'>
```

UPDATE: the requirement was clarified - the image is to flip instantaneously but every half second goes back to its initial orientation.

The keyframes named rotate have been changed so that it stays at 0degrees rotation for half the animation time, flips 180degrees and stays at that for the second half.

Comment: Ok so I'm not sure if I mentioned this but all I need is to find a way to speed up the rotation of the image while leaving the rest unchanged. The image moves around at 10s but the rate at which it transforms (flips about its axis) increases (that's basically what I am looking for).

Comment: Is there a duration CSS property that exclusively affects the image's transform animation but doesn't change anything else?

Comment: Just something that only affects the "transform: rotateY(180deg)" part.

Comment: Ok, I didn't at all realise that you wanted the speed of rotation to increase. Could you say what you want it to increase from (at the start of the 10 seconds) and what speed it ends up rotating at (at the end of the 10 seconds)? And is the acceleration constant?

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back. I would like the speed of the rotation itself to increase to half a second. Keep the image's rotation speed constant throughout the 10second loop. Also please don't change the acceleration of the image itself. If you could please mark with comments the areas that control the rotation so I would know what to do next time.

Comment: Sorry I don’t quite understand that the speed of the rotation is to increase but the the images rotation speed is to be constant.

Comment: My bad, I meant to just increase the rotation speed to half a second.

Comment: The images rotation speed is half a second (0.5s). Sorry I obviously don’t understand what you want. Incidentally you have two class attributes, only one is allowed.

Comment: Actually I just realized something. Instead of an animation, would it be possible for replace the animation with just flipping the image. Basically, instead of having to watch the image perform a flipping animation, we just have the flip on it's axis without an animation.

Comment: Basically, the image still flips but without any animations to it.

Comment: The flip would be instantaneous, the image wouldn't take it's time rotate and flip about its axis.

Comment: I have changed the animation keyframes rotate to make the flip instantaneous.